# Eliminate left recursion in XText

Tags: recursion, xtext, left-recursion

This is part of the grammar of the NuSMV language:

```
BasicExpression:
Constant | '(' BasicExpression ')' | '!' BasicExpression | BasicExpression '&' BasicExpression;
Constant:
BooleanConstant
BooleanConstant: 
'TRUE' | 'FALSE';
```

Unfortunately XText is throwing an exception that states there is left recursion in this grammar.
How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply introduce a new rule (a new tier) like that:

```
BasicExpression:
    firstContent=ExpressionContent ("&" secondContent=ExpressionContent)?
;

ExpressionContent:
    Constant 
    | '(' BasicExpression ')' 
    | '!' BasicExpression 
;
```

That way the rule is not left recursive anymore.

Greeting Krzmbrzl

Comment: This answer rejects `TRUE & TRUE & TRUE` that is allowed in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [this article](http://blog.efftinge.de/2010/08/parsing-expressions-with-xtext.html) or the [official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#expressions), it will explain in detail how to handle recursion in language, and taking into account operator precedence.

Comment: Unfortunately the links are broken.